# BigQuery "Parameterized query job" using the python client library

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, client-library

I have been trying to run a parameterized query using the client libraries in Python and I have tried both the named parameters and the positional parameters methods in the documentation, but neither of them worked.

Here's the positional parameters method:

[image]

And the output:

[image]

The code compiles with no error when I remove the last line of code:

[image]

I have a different function that does not use a parameterized query and works just fine:

[image]

How can I parameterize it with "id"?

I have tried the named parameters and the positional parameters methods described in the documentation but neither of them worked. I'm expecting to get data for the specific id parameter and put it in a data frame.

Comment: Please edit your question to paste your code instead of using a screenshot. Use ``` before and after your code so people can read it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing squar brackets from table name clause.

change

- select * from **[** Table_name **]**

to this

- select * from Table_name